# Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 display issues

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, display, multiple-monitors

I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and have display issues.
I run this on a pretty old PC with a NVIDIA GT220 video card and two monitors.
During the update all goes well and during the reboot everything seems pretty normal too.
When the screen switches to the GUI though one of the two monitors goes blank (actually does not receive input as the monitor) while the other one just shows the purple ubuntu background and no login.
Strangely enough, the monitor that does get the background is the older one with VGA input, while the other monitor has DVI input.
I rebooted in recovery mode and tried to boot default x but that did not seem to work.
I can log into a command line, but do not really know what i should be looking for there.

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging one monitor, then the other if this doesn't work:

Make sure you're entering GRUB, it looks like this: [image]

Look up how to enter it for your system; I believe it's usually esc button. You may have trouble entering it (it's a huge pain in the ass). If you get a blinking dash just reboot and try again.

Once in, press `e` to edit GRUB and add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the line that has `quiet splash` in it.

And definitely check your BIOS to see if `Secure Boot` is off, and turn it off if it's on.